# Alternative to preWindowShellClose() in Eclipse RCP application when using File>Quit or File>Restart

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to do something with the window before the application is closed.
`ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor.preWindowShellClose()` works great for me. The problem is that this method is not called when the user uses menu items: File > Quit or File > Restart. And `Activator.stop()` is too late for me - the window is already closed.

I wonder if there is an alternative method that is called when the application is closed through menu?

Comment: For Eclipse 4 you may be able to use `ISaveHandler` and / or `IWindowCloseHandler` depending on what you want to do.

Comment: There should be a listener called `IWorkbenchListener` which you could add and implement `preShutdown`